# fabric-ca How to generate client certfile and keyfile?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054 -c fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
```

> Error: POST failure [Post https://localhost:7054/enroll: x509:
>   certificate is valid for example.com, not localhost]; not sending

fabric-ca-client-config.yaml

tls:

enabled: true

```
certfiles: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

client:

```
certfile: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
keyfile: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/server.key
```

docker-compose.yaml

ca.org1.example.com:

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
environment:
  - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${PRIVATE_KEY}
ports:
  - "7054:7054"
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
container_name: ca.org1.example.com
```

> fabric-ca-client

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://admin:adminpw@example.com:7054 -c fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
```

> Error: POST failure [Post https://example.com:7054/enroll: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority]; not sending

Comment: What are you using for the fabric-ca-server?  A Docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the TLS server certificate which the fabric-ca-server is using was issued for the **"example.com"** and you are trying to access it as **"localhost"**.

You can

- disable TLS for the fabric-ca-server just to move forward
- created a new TLS certificate for the fabric-ca-server which is valid for **localhost** (I believe that when fabric-ca-server auto generates the TLS cert it should be valid for localhost)
- add an entry to your hosts file mapping **"example.com"** to **127.0.0.1**